# Kubernetes EncryptionConfig Customer Resource Definition

Tags: encryption, kubernetes, etcd

My goal is to encrypt a CRD using an EncryptionConfig.

My initial EncryptionConfig only for secrets works.

```
kind: EncryptionConfig
apiVersion: v1
resources:
 - resources:
    - secrets
    providers:
    - aescbc:
        keys:
        - name: key1
          secret: N/A
    - identity: {}
```

Checking the etcd db directly I can confirm that secrets are now encrypted.

I now want to extend this config to encrypt CRDs. My assumption is that CRD to the list of resources in some way would enable the encryption of the CRDs.

I have tried a number of different permutations of the resources array with no luck.

```
resources:
  - resources:
    - secrets
    - apiextensions.k8s.io/customresourcedefinitions/mycrd


resources:
  - resources:
    - secrets
    - customresourcedefinitions
```

None of these work. Is it possible to encrypt CRDs with the EncryptionConfig? If it is, what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: How did you add encryption config inside kube-apiserver, with `--encryption-provider-config` or `--experimental-encryption-provider-config` flag? What is your k8s version?

Comment: Kube 1.11. I added it using experimental-encryption-provider-config flag.

Comment: Tried in 1.11 k8s version with `--experimental-encryption-provider-config` and in 1.13 with `--encryption-provider-config` flag, works only for secrets and configmaps. Would continue to investigate and update here.

Comment: Seems, it still remains in alpha phase as no further updates so far, confirm encryption secrets and configmaps.